# Can anyone tell me how to store 10 scores and display one score in a line using local storage?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me how to store 10 scores and display one score in a line using local storage?

```js
var score = new Array(10);
var highscore = new Array();
var len = score.length;

function f_score() {
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        if (score[j] < score[j + 1]) {
          temp = score[i];
          score[i] = score[i + 1];
          score[i + 1] = temp;
        }
        localstorage.setItem("highscore", score);
        var highscore = localstorage.getitem("highscore");
      }
    }
    document.write(highscore + "<br>")
```

Comment: Is score `array` ? Ain't you missing `JSON.stringify` ?

Comment: var score = new Array(10);
var highscore = new Array();
var len = score.length;
function score()
{
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{
for(j=0;j<len;j++)
{
if(score[j]<score[j+1])
{
temp=score[i];
score[i]= score[i+1];
score[i+1]=temp;
}
localstorage.setItem("highscore",score);
var highscore = localstorage.getitem("highscore");
}
}
document.write(highscore + "<br>");

Comment: This is my code I need  to print one score in a line

Comment: What error message do you see in the console? You use the name `score` for you array and the function.

Comment: It works fine but it's also printing "," as it is stored as string..

Comment: You need to parse it before priting.

Comment: You use the same name twice, "score" as a variable name and function name. Change one and retest your code to see if your error still exists.

Comment: just use  .replace(/[,]/ ,"");   so it will be "document.write(JSON.stringify(highscore).replace(/[,]/ ,"") + "<br>");"

Comment: I am new to to JavaScript..I used parseInt now it s printing only 1st score

Comment: you need to use .push() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: or print specific array value like document.write(highscore[5]);  remember array start from 0